# Progress Dialog not showing on .Show() in Async method

Tags: web-services, xamarin.android, async-await, progressdialog, retry-logic

I have async method `ExecuteWithRetryAsync` which implements some retry logic and must show ProgressDialog as soon as it is called. Currently the first call to `Show()` never really works. The progress dialog shows only after the `AlertDialog` is confirmed (second comment). How do I make `Show()` at the beginning of ExecuteWithRetryAsync actually show the progress dialog?

```
  public async Task<object> ExecuteWithRetryAsync(string methodName, object[] args)
  {
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Service1).GetMethod(methodName);

// below progress dialog not showing
mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
mDialog.SetMessage("Bitte warten...");
mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
mDialog.Show();

for (; ; )
{
    try
    {
        object result = null;

        try
        {
            // Call web service.
            result = methodInfo?.Invoke(webservice, args);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException tie)
        {
            if (tie.InnerException != null) throw tie.InnerException;
        }

        mDialog?.Dismiss();

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.TraceError("Operation Exception");
        currentRetry++;

        if (/*currentRetry > RetryCount || */!IsTransient(e))
        {
            // If this isn't a transient error or we shouldn't retry, 
            // rethrow the exception.
            throw;
        }
    }

    mDialog?.Dismiss();

    await DisplayAlert(
        context.GetString(Resource.String.timeout),
        context.GetString(Resource.String.retry_operation),
        context.GetString(Resource.String.Ok),
        methodInfo);

    // this progress dialog is showing
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mDialog.SetMessage("Bitte warten...");
    mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
    mDialog.Show();

    await Task.Delay(MaxDelayMilliseconds);
}
}
```

UPDATE: I observed that when connection of device is disabled it takes about ~10-15 secs for `ExecuteWithRetryAsync` to start execution and in the meantime device shows **app not responding dialog** several times, whereas with the connection on it executes immediately. Why that?

UPDATE 2: When I put `await Task.Delay (50)` after calling Show() it does show, but the progress dialog animation is not updating, it's frozen.

UPDATE 3: I put following line `result = methodInfo?.Invoke(Utility.WsHueckmann, args)` inside await Task.Run so it becomes `await Task.Run(() => { result = methodInfo?.Invoke(Utility.WsHueckmann, args); })` and now it's working and spinner is updating.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because there is nothing to await on expect the alert, the dialog  will only show if you await it

Comment: @G.hakim you mean I must put code for showing the progress dialog in separate method and call it with await?

Comment: No what i mean is when you want to show a progress dialog there should be a awaitable method if there is no awaitable method then you cannot do show it

Comment: @G.hakim I'm awaiting `ExecuteWithRetryAsync`

Comment: Then show the dialog before calling the `ExecuteWithRetryAsync` method

Comment: @G.hakim have a look at update 2

Comment: Check my answer out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind your progress not spinning is because it is not indeterminate add the following code and it should work

```
 progress.Indeterminate = true;

 progress.SetProgressStyle(Android.App.ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
```

**Update**

Put the following line

```
result = methodInfo?.Invoke(Utility.WsHueckmann, args)
```

inside await Task.Run so it becomes

```
await Task.Run(() => { result = methodInfo?.Invoke(Utility.WsHueckmann, args); })
```

and now it's working and spinner is updating.

Comment: Did not help. I think the problem is UI Thread is getting blocked and cannot update the spinner animation. If I insert bigger Delay it would spin for some time and then block again.

Comment: Rather than creating a new progress dialog on every button click or whatever even that is why don't you just define your progress in OnCreate method and then just show and dismiss in your methods

Comment: Because there are too many methods calling `ExecuteWithRetryAsync` and it's too much effort to manually wrap every single call with show and dismiss. Whatever, I found a solution, check updated description.

Comment: Well if you want i can update my answer and you can mark it as correct? Would be easier for someone who has the same question